# Absolute DIV inside a relative DIV inside a fixed Div disappears on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

I have a DIV that sticks to the top of the page when you scroll. In order to accomplish this the object is fixed positioned.
The problem is that I also have a div inside that container which is relatively positioned. The relatively positioned DIV displayed fine but the absolutely positioned elements inside of it did not. Now, after the user scrolls and the parent DIV becomes fixed positioned the stuff inside the relative dive (i.e. the absolute stuff) disappears behind the fixed div. 
I had tried some z-index stuff but it seemed to have no effect.
Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c2vqd5fw/
And here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var offset = 0;
  
  /**
  * Always-On-Top Scroll expects HTML in the format: 
  * <div class="scroll-wrapper">
  *     <div class="scroll-aot">...</div>
  * </div>
  **/
  $('.scroll-wrapper').each(function(){   
   if($(this).hasClass('scroll-xs-disabled') && $(window).width() <= 767) {}
   else if($(this).hasClass('scroll-sm-disabled') && $(window).width() <= 991) {}
   else if($(this).hasClass('scroll-md-disabled') && $(window).width() > 991) {}
   else {
    var wrapperTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var scrollAot = $(this).find('.scroll-aot')[0];     
    if(docViewTop >= wrapperTop && !$(scrollAot).hasClass('floating')){
     $(scrollAot).width($(this).width());
     $(scrollAot).css("top", offset);
     $(scrollAot).toggleClass('floating');
     $(this).height($(scrollAot).outerHeight());
    } else if (docViewTop < wrapperTop && $(scrollAot).hasClass('floating')){ 
     $(scrollAot).removeAttr('style'); // oh no it has no style!
     $(this).removeAttr('style');
     $(scrollAot).toggleClass('floating');
    }
    
    offset = offset + $(scrollAot).height();
    docViewTop = docViewTop + $(scrollAot).height();
   }
  });    
 });
    $('.toggle-switch').click(function(){
  $(this).children().toggleClass('off');
 });
});
```

```css
.stuff-above{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:grey;
}
.stuff-below{
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    background-color:grey;
}
.scroll-wrapper{
 width: 100%;
}
.scroll-wrapper.small{
 width: 50%;
}
.scroll-wrapper.floating{
 position: relative;    
}
.scroll-aot{
 width: 100%;
    background-color:green;
}
.scroll-aot.floating{
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1000;
}
.toggle-switch{
 z-index:2000;
    display: inline-block;
 position:relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 cursor:pointer;    
 box-sizing:content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
 width:64px;
 height:32px;
 padding:0px;
 border:2px solid #999999;
 border-radius:2px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
.toggle-switch .content{
    position:absolute;
 z-index:2000;
    top:0px;
 left:0px;
 width:200%;
 height:32px;
 transition: left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
 -moz-transition: left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
 -webkit-transition: left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
 -o-transition: left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
}
.toggle-switch .content.off{
 left:-64px;
 transition: left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
 -moz-transition: left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
 -webkit-transition: left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
 -o-transition: left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
}
.toggle-switch .content #on{
 background-color: #2FCCFF;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
.toggle-switch .content #off{
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 color: #999999;
 text-align: right;
}
.toggle-switch .content .option{
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 height: 32px;
 padding: 0px 7px;
 line-height: 32px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.toggle-switch .slider{
 z-index:2000;
    background-color:#bbbbbb;
 display: inline-block;
 width:34px;
 height:32px;
 border-left:1px solid #999999;
 border-right:1px solid #999999;
 position: absolute;
 right:-1px;    
 transition: right 0.3s ease-in 0s;
 -moz-transition: right 0.3s ease-in 0s;
 -webkit-transition: right 0.3s ease-in 0s;
 -o-transition: right 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.toggle-switch .slider.off{
 right: 32px;
 transition: right 0.3s ease-in 0s;
 -moz-transition: right 0.3s ease-in 0s;
 -webkit-transition: right 0.3s ease-in 0s;
 -o-transition: right 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.toggle-switch .slider img{
    max-width:32px;
 max-height:32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stuff-above"></div>
<div class="scroll-wrapper">
    <div class="scroll-aot">
        <div class="onOffColumn" title="Friends from LinkedIn">
            <div class="toggleSliderCntnr">
                <div id="liGroup" class="toggle-switch">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div id="on" class="option">On</div>
                        <div id="off" class="option">Off</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider">
                        <img class="toggleImg" src="" alt="Linkedin"/>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="stuff-below"></div>
```

The strangest thing is that if you interact with the empty box (when the blue is hidden) the absolutely positioned stuff reappears. 
Thoughts?

Comment: change markup of html or position all three with absolute

Comment: The problem lies in the `overflow: hidden;` attribute for the `.toggle-switch` class. If you remove it, then your scroll problem goes away. Unfortunately I don't know why this is the case. If I did, I would have responded with an answer rather than a comment. Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf3bhwr4/) to show this working. I somewhat fixed the switch style without using overflow, but some more TLC is needed here.

Comment: It's working fine in my test in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I didn't exactly figure it out but I re-wrote the toggle so it doesn't use absolute positioning or relative positioning at all and now it works cleanly.
For anyone who wants to check it out, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/c2vqd5fw/

```css
.toggle-switch .content{
 width:150%;
 height:32px;
 transition: margin-left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
 -moz-transition: margin-left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
 -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
 -o-transition: margin-left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
}
.toggle-switch .content.off{
 margin-left:-32px;
 transition: margin-left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
 -moz-transition: margin-left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
 -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
 -o-transition: margin-left 0.4s ease-in 0s;
}
.toggle-switch .content #on{
 background-color: #2FCCFF;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
.toggle-switch .content #off{
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 color: #999999;
 text-align: center;
}
.toggle-switch .content .option{
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 width: 31px;
 height: 32px;
 padding: 0px 7px;
 line-height: 32px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.toggle-switch .slider{
    background-color:#bbbbbb;
 display: inline-block;
 float:left;
 border-left:1px solid #999999;
 border-right:1px solid #999999;
    
}
.toggle-switch .slider img{
    max-width:32px;
 max-height:32px;
    min-width:32px;
 min-height:32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="liGroup" class="toggle-switch">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="on" class="option">On</div>
    <div class="slider">
      <img class="toggleImg" src="" alt="Linkedin"/>
    </div>
    <div id="off" class="option">Off</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```